# Fancy page style conflict with bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, header-footer

I am using the following code to in my LaTeX document to create bibliography.

```
\lhead{References}

\chead{}

\rhead{\thepage}

\pagestyle{plain}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{References/references}
```

This code shows header only on the first page of bibliography and other 4 pages don't have headers. 
Would someone please help me to solve this problem. I would like to have headers on all pages of bibliography.

Thanks.

Comment: Then why do you use \pagestyle{plain}? Beside this: don't sent code snippets. Always try to make a small but complete example to avoid that important informations like the class is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution with the report class, which places the bibliography on a separate page. Adjustments were made with the `fancyhdr` package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy} 
\fancyhf{} 


\fancyhead[C]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}} 

\fancyhead[R]{\thepage} 

\begin{document}

\chapter{test}
Text \nocite*

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{Referecenes/references}
\end{document}
```

You can adjust further details of the header according to your neads using the `fancyhdr` package.